# Add Lookup column to SharePoint list using Flow/Power Automate and Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-flow, power-automate

I am trying to add a Lookup column from a SharePoint list using Microsoft Flow(Power automate). The flow retries once and says "Bad Gateway". I'm not sure why the below is not working given that I have included the 4 necessary things - FieldTypeKind, Title, LookupList, LookupField.

The aim is to get a column added to the Projects list, which is a lookup from the Workstream list.

I've tried using the LookupList name rather than ID and it didn't work. I have tried changing "Title: Workstream" to "Title: Title" which didn't work. The site address is accurate and I have been able to add SP.FieldChoice, SP.FieldText columns, which leads me to believe it's the body that needs something changing.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions given [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-Lookup-column-in-SharePoint-list-using-the-HTTP-Request/td-p/440704)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below configurations in **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action to create a lookup field:

[image]

For more information, check below official documentation by Microsoft:

[FieldLookup and FieldUser resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182%28v%3Doffice.15%29#fieldlookup-and-fielduser-resources)

Comment: This worked thanks. I need to include addfield in uri and parameters in the body

Comment: Yes. Glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.